# Attach div to a search textbox to create Gmail like search box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, search-box

I am creating a Gmail like search box where I click on the text box and it opens a new div where I can enter search criteria for various fields.
How can I tightly attach the TextBox('#searchTextBox) or the div containing the textbox with the div for search form ('#gmailSearchBox)?
Also I am using bootstrap responsive and thus the location and size of the text box changes. So just setting div style display:block and display:none doesnt work.
Thanks.

Html Code:

```
<div style="border:1px solid grey; border-radius:3px; max-width:300px; padding-right:0px; padding-left:0px;"class="container-fluid">
    <div style="left:0px;right:20px; line-height:inherit; float:left; width:100%; ">
        <input id="searchTextBox" type="text" style="border:none; width:95%; line-height:inherit; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;"> 
        <a id="showSearchBox" href="#" style="height:20px">
             <span class="caret" style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%"> </span>
        </a>
    </input>
</div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Search" Class="btn btn-primary" /><br>
Various<br>
Other<br>
Information<br>
Goes <br>
Here<br>
<div id='gmailSearchBox' class="gmailSearchBox" style="position:absolute; display:none; border:1px solid grey">
<form action="" method="post">
    From:<input type="text" id="fromDate">
    <br/>
    To: <input type="text" id="toDate">
    <br/>
    Type:<select id="logType">
            <option>--Select Type--</option>
        </select>
    <br/>
    Text:<input type="text" id="searchText">
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
$('#showSearchBox').click(showSearchBox);
function showSearchBox() {
    $('#gmailSearchBox').css('display','block')
}
```

JsFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/7FBax/

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question! What do you mean by 'How can I tightly attach the TextBox'? If this is a styling question, show us how you want it to look!

Comment: @nimrod I want something similar to Gmail search box. The div containing the search form should remain at the bottom of the search textbox. If you look at the JsFiddle link, on clicking the down arrow in the text box, the search form displays at the very bottom. But how can I set the search form such that no matter where ever I have the search textbox, the search form stays attached to it. Hope this clarifies the question. A snapshot of gmail search box [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/96EbH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with css, you'll probably need to change your markup a little. See the following fiddle, which does what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/97BwC/1/

The revised Markup:

```
<div id="search" style=""class="container-fluid">
<div id="searchInputWrapper" style="">
    <input type="text" style=""> <a id="showSearchBox" href="#" style="height:20px">
             <span class="caret" style="vertical-align:middle; height:100%"> </span>
        </a>

    </input>
</div>
<div id='gmailSearchBox' class="gmailSearchBox" style="">
    <form action="" method="post">From:
        <input type="text" id="fromDate">
        <br/>To:
        <input type="text" id="toDate">
        <br/>Type:
        <select id="logType">
            <option>--Select Type--</option>
        </select>
        <br/>Text:
        <input type="text" id="searchText">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</div>
```

The css:

```
    #search {
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid grey;
        border-radius:3px;
        max-width:300px;
        padding-right:0px;
        padding-left:0px;
    }
    #searchInputWrapper {
        left:0px;
        right:20px;
        line-height:inherit;
        float:left;
        width:100%;
    }
    #searchInputWrapper input {
        border:none;
        width:95%;
        line-height:inherit;
        padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    #gmailSearchBox {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:-212px;
        right:0;
        display:none;
        border:1px solid grey;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
```

**Update:**

If the height of the search box isn't static, you can use javascript to set the bottom offset. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GPTJ4/2/

And here's the revised handler:

```
$('#showSearchBox').click(showSearchBox);

function showSearchBox() {
    var height = 0,
        $searchBox = $('#gmailSearchBox');

    $searchBox.css({display:'block'});

    //get the height of the search box
    height = $searchBox.height();

    //set the offset equal to the height
    $searchBox.css({bottom:-height +'px'});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but the 'bottom:-212px' makes this hard coded. It works in the fiddle example but not everywhere. Any way to make it dynamic? No matter where 'searchInputWrapper' is placed, 'gmailSearchBox' should be tied below it.

Comment: @darsheets As long as the height of the dropdown is constant, it will work everywhere. The offset on the bottom should be the same as the height of the dropdown box. Just change 212px to whatever height you're using....

Comment: @darsheets Please see my revised javascript code if the height of the searchbox can change.

Answer (score 0):

It would work as you intend if you place your #gmailSearchBox in the same div that contains the input.  You will probably want to set a background-color for the #gmailSearchBox as well.